# HaxeFlixel Unexpected & (amp) Character

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to get HaxeFlixel working. It works with `lime test neko` but doesn't work on `lime test neko -debug`. It says:

> /usr/share/haxelib/flixel/4,6,0/flixel/effects/particles/FlxEmitter.hx:28: characters 34-35 : Unexpected &

And here's how the `FlxEmitter.hx` file looks around line 28:

```
typedef FlxEmitter = FlxTypedEmitter<FlxParticle>;

#if (haxe_ver >= "4.0.0")
class FlxTypedEmitter<T:FlxSprite & IFlxParticle> extends FlxTypedGroup<T> 
#else
class FlxTypedEmitter<T:(FlxSprite, IFlxParticle)> extends FlxTypedGroup<T>
#end
{
    /**
     * Set your own particle class type here. The custom class must extend `FlxParticle`. Default is `FlxParticle`.
     */
    public var particleClass:Class<T> = cast FlxParticle;
```

Here is my machine specifications:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64bit
- Lime Command-Line Tools (7.2.1)
- HaxeFlixel command-line tools (1.4.3)
- Installed Flixel version: 4.6.0
- Haxe Compiler 4.0.0
- OpenFL version 8.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the code already checks the Haxe version in order to be compatible with both Haxe 3.4 and 4. This is necessary because the new [type parameter constraint](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameter-constraints.html) syntax is not backwards-compatible.

Considering that, the only explanation is that you're using a build of Haxe 4 that hadn't introduced the new [intersection type syntax](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-intersection-types.md#intersection-types) using `&` yet. The first release with this feature was Haxe 4.0.0-preview.4. I suggest you try updating to the latest release, [Haxe 4.0.0-rc.1](https://haxe.org/download/version/4.0.0-rc.1/).

> Haxe Compiler 4.0.0

Note that Haxe [didn't mention](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5719) anything about preview releases in `haxe --version` until Haxe 4.0.0-preview.4. So while it may *look* like you have the final release of 4.0.0 installed, that actually hasn't happened yet and it's one of the early preview builds.